# How to redraw custom controls that are embedded in other custom controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building an app that has to be capable of plot a data series in C#. For this task, I started to build every part of the chart application as it follows:

1. An outer container represented by a class derived from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl, which is a container for the chart axes, plot area and chart title. This class has also the responsability to redraw all its child controls(by invalidate them).
2. A class derived from System.Windows.Forms.Control to represent the chart axes. The chart is supposed to have multiple Y-Axes and an unique X-Axis.
3. A class derived from System.Windows.Forms.Control where the data series will be shown.

The last two classes doesn't have a design view as I wrote them without using the templates provided for VS2010. Regardless, I set multiple properties of them to calculate their place and size within the container class, obviously this process is performed before the controls are drawn.

Well, the issue raises when I tried to Invalidate them from the container class. The classes have override the OnPaint method to handle the Paint event, which I trigger from the container class. The code for the OnPaint method in the container class looks like this

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        Axis1.Invalidate();
        Axis2.Invalidate();
        PlotArea.Invalidate();
    }
```

And as I stated above, every class has its respective OnPaint method. So guys, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Okay John, I will have in mind the next time.